# Wireless Access Point - Can't ping other machines on the wireless network

Tags: windows, networking, wifi, ping, access-point

I have a wireless access point (Netgear), and I have it setup so that it has an IP address in the current subnet (let's say 192.168.2.0, subnet mask of 255.255.255.0).  The machine that it is connected to via ethernet cable has an IP in the same subnet as the AP.  The machines that are connected to the AP via the wireless connection also have an IP address in the same subnet as the rest of the network (192.168.2.0).

All machines can ping the access point, but they cannot ping each other.  I don't totally understand why, because there is connection and all of the machines are in the same subnet.  I realize this is a layer 3 device, but is there an issue because of this AP's lack of gateway capabilities? (i.e. no routing table, etc.)

Comment: Are you perhaps connecting to the WAN port on the wireless router rather than a lan port? Also some access points have a security 'feature' where wireless clients are disallowed from seeing each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible you should try and direct the logs from the AP to a syslog server and possibly discover from them what is going on.

You could also try and use Wireshark to see what is happening to the traffic on your network and see if it is the AP that is isolating the connections or if it is a firewalling issue on the hosts.

Answer (score 2):

Netgear has a security feature that may be enabled, useful when you have wireless guests connecting that don't trust, but likely not useful in your case:

> Enable Wireless Isolation
>   If checked, the wireless client under this SSID can only access internet and it can‘t access other wireless clients even under the same SSID, Ethernet clients or this device. Other clients can‘t access the wireless client, either.